# compute the mean of a sparse matrix by ignoring zeros

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I've been trying to find a way to compute the column-wise mean of a sparse matrix, ignoring the zero values. for a numpy array I could do this:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
arr[arr == 0] = np.nan
means = np.nanmean(arr, axis=0)
```

or I could do:

```
#I don't understand why tmean axis=1 doesn't work. I ended up with this
f = lambda x: tmean(x,(0,None),(False,None))
means = list(map(f,arr.T))
```

finally, I want to keep the above-average values in each column

```
arr[arr<means.reshape(1,arr.shape[1])]=0

array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 5.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

How do I achieve this with a sparse matrix? `arr_csr = csr_matrix(arr)`

Comment: So have you successfully created the `arr_csr`?  I think you could use `arr_csr.sum(axis=1)/arr_csr.getnnz(axis=1)` - the row sum divided by the row non-zero count.  I'll test this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [339]: arr = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
     ...:                 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
     ...:                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
     ...:                 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
     ...:                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4], 
     ...:                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5], 
     ...:                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])                         
In [340]: sparse                                                                
Out[340]: <module 'scipy.sparse' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py'>
In [341]: M =sparse.csr_matrix(arr)                                             
In [342]: M                                                                     
Out[342]: 
<7x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 17 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [343]: M.sum(axis=1)                                                         
Out[343]: 
matrix([[6],
        [3],
        [3],
        [2],
        [4],
        [5],
        [1]])
In [344]: M.getnnz(axis=1)                                                      
Out[344]: array([6, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [345]: M.sum(axis=1).A1/M.getnnz(axis=1)                                     
Out[345]: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 4., 5., 1.])
In [346]: M.mean(axis=1)                                                        
Out[346]: 
matrix([[0.66666667],
        [0.33333333],
        [0.33333333],
        [0.22222222],
        [0.44444444],
        [0.55555556],
        [0.11111111]])
```

Comment: to find the below-average elements I do `M_lil[M_lil<np.atleast_2d(means2).T]=0`. is there any more effecient approach?

Comment: That may be too much address in a ocmment.  For a dense array it looks right (to set items below the row mean to 0), but without experimenting or looking the code, I don't know how well the `lil` format handles this.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy` sparse matrices have the attributes data and indices, you can use these two to calculate the mean along the column axis and further check which are above average. Example:

```
row = np.array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
col = np.array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
m = csr_matrix((data,(row,col)),shape=(3,3))
# m = [[1,0,2],
#      [0,0,3],
#      [4,5,6]]
print(m.data)
print(m.indices)
```

Edit: A little bit of background to csr-format. Each entry in `m.indices` (let's say i, `m.indices[i]`) represents the column-index of the respective entry in `m.data` (`m.data[i]`).

Example taken from scipy-documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

Comment: `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` instances have no `col` attribute. A `col` attribute is only provided on `coo_matrix` instances.

Comment: It happens to be the case that the `indptr` array of a CSR matrix can be treated like the `col` array of a COO matrix, though there is no such analogue of the `row` array.

Comment: (oh, right, `indices`, not `indptr` - `indptr` is a different thing)